# Error creating a spatial database. ERROR : could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so"

Tags: database, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I am running `PostgreSQL 9.1` with `Postgis 2.0` on `Fedora 15`.

When trying to install the raster support,

```
psql -d database -f rtpostgis.sql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

I get the following error

```
psql:rtpostgis.sql:46: ERROR:  
     could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": libhdf5.so.6: 
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A `locate libhdf5.so.6` gives the following paths.

```
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6.0.4
```

Reinstalling the `GDAL` from the repositories did not solve the problem. The version of the installed `GDAL`.

```
gdal.x86_64                                1.7.3-14.fc15                @updates
```

Comment: Although Fedora 15 is no longer supported, you can also try to use the [PGDG RPMs](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) for PostgreSQL 9.1/PostGIS 2.0. The [instructions for Fedora 16](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Fedora16pgdg) are similar.

Comment: @MikeToews I am using the RPMs from [PGDG RPMs](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) repo itself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checked for whether `/etc/ld.so.conf` has a reference to the path `/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib`.

by doing  `ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5`.

Which did not output anything.

On checking that `/etc/ld.so.conf` had  `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`.

Checked for the files in directory `ld.so.conf.d`.
One of the conf file in `include ld.so.conf.d` was `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-x8664.conf` which contained `/usr/lib64/atlas`.

So I,

- created a file called `gdal.conf` in the directory `ld.so.conf.d`.
- Added the string `/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib` to the file.
- Ran [`ldconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).
- Now, `ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5` had the paths to `llibhdf5` files.

After doing the above, postgis raster support installation went smoothly.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is `ldconfig`, and everything should be good