# Postgis Extension install PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-extensions

When I try to enable PostGis extension on my database I receive the following:

```
postgis=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": libhdf5.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I used find -name to find the files:

```
[root@digihaul3-pc /]# find -name rtpostgis-2.1.so
./usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so

[root@digihaul3-pc /]# find -name libhdf5.so.6
./usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6
./usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/libhdf5.so.6
./usr/lib/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6
```

Comment: Which operating system are you running? You might find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415239/postgres-create-postgis-extension-error-with-centos-6) -- but without more details I can't advise further.

Comment: CentOS, Ruby on rails 3, ruby 1.9.3

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'm guessing you've found most of the other help I've seen which is that there appear to be issues installing in CentOS. However, [this looks most useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768644/error-when-trying-to-run-create-extension-postgis?rq=1) and [this may also help, although not about CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915928/error-when-installing-postgis-extension-to-postgresql-database?rq=1). Sorry I can't help further, I don't use CentOS much because of issues like this...

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Thinking Monkey @ on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888487/error-creating-a-spatial-database-error-could-not-load-library-usr-pgsql-9?rq=1)

it is for fordora 15. But i tried everything else and this actually fixed my issue and allowed me to install the postgis extentions. Doesn't take long to install.

Thinking Monkeys Post:

```
Checked for whether /etc/ld.so.conf has a reference to the path /usr/lib64/mpich2/lib.

by doing  ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5.

Which did not output anything.

On checking that /etc/ld.so.conf had  include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf.

Checked for the files in directory ld.so.conf.d. One of the conf file in include ld.so.conf.d was /etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-x8664.conf which contained /usr/lib64/atlas.

So I,

    created a file called gdal.conf in the directory ld.so.conf.d.
    Added the string /usr/lib64/mpich2/lib to the file.
    Ran ldconfig.
    Now, ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5 had the paths to llibhdf5 files.
    After doing the above, postgis raster support installation went smoothly.
```

Comment: its looking for .6 but my libhdf5 files are all .7